# Php - socket_read with pthreads

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, pthreads

I know socket and thread is horrible in php... I'm just trying to connect my php file with socket to my server.
The problem is I got nothing from socket_read (no datas no error just returning an empty string) and I think pthread kill automatically the socket.
For now I don't need thread but I need to keep it to use it later.

My code:

```
<?php

class test extends Threaded
{
    /*

    */
    public function         __construct($ip, $port, $debug = false)
    {
        $this->debug = $debug;
        $this->ip = $ip;
        $this->port = $port;
    }

    /*

    */
    public function         __destruct()
    {
        socket_close($this->connect);
    }

    /*

    */
    public function         start()
    {

        if (!($this->connect = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP))) {
            throw new Exception('SOCKET_CREATE');
        }

        if (!socket_set_option($this->connect, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array('sec' => 5, 'usec' => 0))) {
            throw new Exception('SOCKET_SET_OPTION');
        }

        if (!socket_connect($this->connect, $this->ip, $this->port)) {
            throw new Exception('SOCKET_CONNECT');
        }

        $getMsg = socket_read($this->connect, 255);
        echo $getMsg;
    }

}
```

Do you know how it can works?

EDIT: I tried again today and my script works, I don't understand sometime it works sometime not ....
EDIT2: I copied my server file script to an other server with much much more traffic and it works ! So why it works on the server 2 and not on server 1 ?